# self.isLinkActive = true will not load the model view

Tags: swiftui

Why can SwiftUI not just load the view it shouldn't b e this hard to do something that could be done in UIKit in one stupid line. the button should simply load what its told to load in this case VideoList(viewModel: .init()) there should be no problem.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
@State private var isLinkActive = false

let layout = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))
    ]

var body: some View {
  
    
    ///Top Bar layout
    

            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image("Home")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: CGFloat(30), height: CGFloat(30), alignment: .leading)
                    }).padding(.leading, CGFloat(20))
                    .padding(.top, 15)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }

                HStack {
                    Text("app")
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Menu"))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding(.top, 15)
                }

            }

    
    
    ///Setup app FEED LINE

    
    HStack{
        Text("app FEED")
            .padding(.leading, 20.0)
            .padding(.top, 100.0)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(Color("Menu"))
        Spacer()
    }
    
        
    ///Setup Welcom messages
    
    

    HStack{
        Text("Good morning")
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .padding(.leading, 20.0)
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(Color("Menu"))
        Spacer()
        
        Text("...")
            .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(.trailing, 20.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }

    
    
    /// Setup navigation home
    
    
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 5) {
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("app")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("app")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
            
            Button(action: {
                self.isLinkActive = true
    }) {
                Image("app")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("app")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("app")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("app")
            }
            
         //Add correct images Direction and Contact us
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("app")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("app")
            }
            
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)

            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
        .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
    
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .background(
        NavigationLink(destination: VideoList(viewModel: .init()), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        .hidden()
    )
    }

}





struct VideoList: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
@ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: ViewModel
@State private var isRefreshing = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(viewModel.videos.sorted { $0.id > $1.id}, id: \.id) { video in
            NavigationLink(
            destination: VideoDetails(viewModel: VideoDetails.ViewModel(video: video))) {
                VideoRow(video: video)
                
            }
        }
        .onPullToRefresh(isRefreshing: $isRefreshing, perform: {
            self.viewModel.fetchVideos()
        })
        .onReceive(viewModel.$videos, perform: { _ in
            self.isRefreshing = false
        })
        .navigationBarTitle(viewModel.navigationBarTitle)
    }
    .onAppear(perform: viewModel.fetchVideos)
}
}

#if DEBUG
struct VideoList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VideoList(viewModel: .init())
    }
}
}
#endif
```

The button on line 109 does not load the VideoList(viewModel: .init()) ViewModel when requested to do so.

Answer (score 0):

NavigationView {} was forgotten however the UI is still messed up currently

and adding an HStack fixed.... ugh hope this helps the next guy not have to spend 3 days on it